# C struct return pointer, store in reference

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

I have a simple question which I am trying to figure out why...

I have a function that returns a struct pointer. And I have a struct variable 'a'.

```
&a = somefunc(...) // returns a pointer to my struct.
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Why does the above not work, while the following works...

```
struct whatever *b = somefunc(...)
```

My thinking is, in both cases, I am returning something of type struct whatever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `address of` operator `&` yields an `rvalue` which is the memory address of its operand. You can't have an rvalue on the left side of an assignment. Hence you need an `lvalue` and to store the address of a variable, you need a pointer type variable.

```
struct mystruct {
    int marks;
    char grade;
};

// a is of type struct mystruct. 
// stores a value of this type

struct mystruct a; 

// b is pointer to struct mystruct type.
// stores the address of a variable of this type.

struct mystruct *b;

b = &a; // assign b the address of a
```

Answer (score 1):

`&a` means "give me address of a", which is not a l-value (you cannot assign anything to it).
In second example `*b` is a valid l-value

You can think of `&a`  returning 100. You cannot do 100 = something.
While `b` is a valid variable (of type pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Only a pointer can hold addresses, you are trying to assign an address to an address i.e. a value to a value in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

`&a` means `address of a`. You can't assign anything to an `address of something`. Think of it as your email address in general -- people can ask you for it and they can use it after you gave it to them, but they can't change it.

On the other hand, `*b` is `a variable that contains an address of struct whatever`. That's something that you can store a value in. In email terms that would be a whiteboard with dedicated space where you write your email address. If someone wants to change it, they can do it.